# Issues with ifstream reading CSV data

Tags: c++, csv

Non-working code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
int main(){
int id; string name;char comma ; double money;
ifstream read("testfile.csv");
 while (read >> id >> comma>> name >> comma >> money)
 {cout << id <<comma<<name<<comma<<money<<  endl ;}
 read.close();
 _getch();
return 0;}
```

The csv file data & structure:

`1,user1,999
 2,user2,33
 3,user3,337`

But, the following works fine. Why so?

`while (read >> id >>comma>>name)
     {cout << id<<comma<<name <<endl ;}`

Comment: Some good reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, was trying to figure out why the alternative codes worked.

Answer (score 3):

When you read a string using `>>`, it reads a *space delimited* string. If there is no space in the text you read, it will read until the end of the line (as newline is a space).

Because of this the "parsing" of the input will after a little while be out of sync with the contents from the file, and will lead to an error when attempting to read one of the numbers.

Comment: +1 -- where to find/learn  the following info? 
**When you read a string using >>, it reads a space delimited string** 
**as newline is a space**

Comment: @CowardlyDog For most information I usually go to [this reference wiki](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). The [input/output reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) have of course a section on [`std::basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) (which is the base class for all input streams) which in turn have links to the [in-class member `operator>>` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) as well as the [non-member `operator>>` overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) (used for strings).

Comment: @CowardlyDog [Continued...] For reading strings, the last reference contains the text "The extraction stops if one of the following conditions are met: ...a whitespace character ... is found." Ergo, reading strings is space-delimited. :)